# Improving parametric model for sinusoidal regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I am trying to model the curve below.

[image]

I am fitting the data points (dots)

```
  x    y  
0  0.00000000  
2 -0.02367573  
4 -0.07158837 
6  0.00000000  
8  0.00000000 
10  0.12983607  
12  0.30475756  
14  0.42666667  
16  0.41228752 
18  0.28382022  
20  0.02562825 
22  0.00000000  
24  0.00000000
```

to this function

```
y ~ a0 + a1 * x + a2 * sin(omega*x) + a3 * cos(omega*x) + a4 * sin(2 * omega*x) + a5 * cos(2 * omega*x) + a6 * sin(3 * omega*x) + a7 * cos(3 * omega*x)
```

However this function cannot represent the plateau that is present in the data between x =5 and x= 10. Can anyone help me to improve my model?

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing.  What are you trying to do, interpolate the data points?

Comment: @MatthewDrury yes that's correct. You can see that the two points between 5 and 10 have the same y value

Comment: If you want to interpolate, I would look into cubic splines.

Comment: Try an additive model (if you post the data used in the plot I'll provide you with a full answer), as it will give a local fit, depending on the smoothness you restrict the splines to.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson I have included the data but unfortunately I need a parametric model..

Comment: The additive model I fitted below is semi-parametric; once you have the basis functions it is a penalised regression model. The basis function used to fit the spline in the additive model aren't conceptually different from the cos/sin bases you used or polynomial bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data, here are two approaches in R

```
txt <- "x    y  
0  0.00000000  
2 -0.02367573  
4 -0.07158837 
6  0.00000000  
8  0.00000000 
10  0.12983607  
12  0.30475756  
14  0.42666667  
16  0.41228752 
18  0.28382022  
20  0.02562825 
22  0.00000000  
24  0.00000000"
dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```

### Fit an additive model

This option isn't going to interpolate the data by passing through each data point, but it will treat the data as noisy observations of some smooth underlying function.

```
library("mgcv")
m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = dat)

pdat <- with(dat, data.frame(x = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 200)))
pdat <- transform(pdat, fitted = predict(m, pdat))
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
lines(fitted ~ x, data = pdat, col = "red")
```

This approach is close to the one you used but allows the functional form to be determined from the data whereas you specified a sine/cosine function.

### Interpolating spline

If you want to interpolate the data by passing through the observations, then an interpolating spline will get you what you want.

```
sfun <- with(dat, splinefun(x = x, y = y))
pdat <- transform(pdat, fitted2 = sfun(x))

plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
lines(fitted ~ x, data = pdat, col = "red")
lines(fitted2 ~ x, data = pdat, col = "blue")
```

The final plot comparing the two approaches is shown below

[image]

Which of these you want will depend on whether you want the function to pass through all the data points or not.